# Writing out literal value of variables to file

Tags: file-io, tcl

I have this daunting chunk of code:

```
exec zip -r $FULLPATH error.log [ append datetime $RECENT ".bwdb" ] [ append txt $testName  ".txt" ] [ append lancap $testName "-lan.cap" ] \
        [ append lanmcap $testName "-lan-m.cap" ] [ append wancap $testName "-wan.cap" ] [ append wanmcap $testName "-wan-m.cap" ] [ append conf $confFile ".conf" ] \
        start.txt start-lan.cap start-lan-m.cap start-wan.cap start-wan-m.cap [ append comments "comments-" $RECENT ".bwc" ]
```

Which is actually just zipping a bunch of files together. I'm changing the way I generate the zip files (more accurately I'm changing *when* I generate them). The way I've decided to do it is to save every command into a text file and then just go through every command in the file when I need to create them. The issue is that I have a bunch of variables that I need to convert into literal form.

Does anyone know how I could convert this command into it's literal values and store it into a text file?

Edit: I'd also be willing to hear other suggestions that solve the same issue, and/or any pros/cons in doing it the way I'm suggesting.

Edit2: Thanks for all the help, I opted to do this:

```
set data123 "exec zip -r $FULLPATH error.log [ append datetime $RECENT \".bwdb\" ] [ append txt $testName  \".txt\" ] [ append lancap $testName \"-lan.cap\" ] \
        [ append lanmcap $testName \"-lan-m.cap\" ] [ append wancap $testName \"-wan.cap\" ] [ append wanmcap $testName \"-wan-m.cap\" ] [ append conf $confFile \".conf\" ] \
        start.txt start-lan.cap start-lan-m.cap start-wan.cap start-wan-m.cap [ append comments \"comments-\" $RECENT \".bwc\" ]"

set datafile123 "datafile123.txt"
set fileId123 [ open $datafile123 "w" ]
puts $fileId123 $data123
close $fileId123
```

However, when I look at the resulting file I see:

```
exec zip -r /home/IOL/TR069_Certification/Results/TEST_Round99_GetRPCMethods_CDR1_20130410172812 error.log 20130410172812.bwdb20130410172812".bwdb" GetRPCMethods.txtGetRPCMethods".txt" GetRPCMethods-lan.capGetRPCMethods"-lan.cap"  GetRPCMethods-lan-m.capGetRPCMethods"-lan-m.cap" GetRPCMethods-wan.capGetRPCMethods"-wan.cap" GetRPCMethods-wan-m.capGetRPCMethods"-wan-m.cap" IOL.confIOL".conf"  start.txt start-lan.cap start-lan-m.cap start-wan.cap start-wan-m.cap comments-20130410172812.bwc"comments-"20130410172812".bwc"
```

Which appears to be making a second copy of the concatenated string at the end of each append and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Why not as simple string? You know that a `"` string can span multiple lines?

```
set f [open /p/t/f w]
puts $f "error.log
$datetume$RECENT.bwdb
$txt$testName.txt
$lancap$testName-lan.cap
$lanmcap$testName-lan-m.cap
$wancap$testName-wan.cap
$wanmcap$testName-$wan.cap
$conf$confFile.conf
start.txt
start-lan.cap
start-lan-m.cap
start-wan.cap
start-wan-m.cap
${comments}comments-$RECENT.bwc"
close $f
```

**Edit**: You should not indent the follow up lines, otherwise this indentation will show up in the resulting file.
I personally usually use a template file, and use `subst` to replace the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would basically just do what you proposed: wrote the literal values to a text file.
One way to do that would be as simple as this:

```
set s ""
append s \
  error.log \n \
  $datetime $RECENT .bwdb \n \
  $txt $testName .txt \n \
  $lancap $testName -lan.cap \n \
  $lanmcap $testName -lan-m.cap \n \
  $wancap $testName -wan.cap \n \
  $wanmcap $testName -wan-m.cap \n \
  $conf $confFile .conf \n \
  start.txt \n start-lan.cap \n \
  start-lan-m.cap \n start-wan.cap \n start-wan-m.cap \n \
  $comments comments- $RECENT .bwc
set f [open /path/to/file w]
puts $f $s
close $f
```

This would create a text files with one filename per line.

Another — more direct — rework could look like this:

```
set files [list]
lappend files \
  error.log \
  [ append datetime $RECENT ".bwdb" ] \
  [ append txt $testName  ".txt" ] \
  [ append lancap $testName "-lan.cap" ] \
  [ append lanmcap $testName "-lan-m.cap" ] \
  [ append wancap $testName "-wan.cap" ] \
  [ append wanmcap $testName "-wan-m.cap" ] \
  [ append conf $confFile ".conf" ] \
  start.txt start-lan.cap start-lan-m.cap start-wan.cap start-wan-m.cap \
  [ append comments "comments-" $RECENT ".bwc" ]
set f [open /path/to/file w]
puts $f [join $files \n]
close $f
```

I'm suspicious about this usage of `append` though as here this command seems to be used solely for its side-effect. `append` takes the strings of its second to last arguments and appends them to a string located in a variable whose name is passed as its first argument, returning the resulting string.  And I dislike the fact that in your original example (and in my second one) `append` seems to be used just for that return value.

So probably a more idiomatic way would be to use the Tcl's way of simple string concatenation, like this:

```
set files [list]
lappend files \
  error.log \
  ${datetime}${RECENT}.bwdb \
  ${txt}${testName}.txt \
  ${lancap}${testName}-lan.cap \
  ${lanmcap}${testName}-lan-m.cap \
  ${wancap}${testName}-wan.cap \
  ${wanmcap}${testName}-wan-m.cap \
  ${conf}${confFile}.conf \
  start.txt start-lan.cap start-lan-m.cap start-wan.cap start-wan-m.cap \
  ${comments}comments-${RECENT}.bwc
set f [open /path/to/file w]
puts $f [join $files \n]
close $f
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the tips on TCL. I was kind of just dumped into a tcl project at work and I've been self-teaching myself as I go, so these things crop up every now and then.